# Pandas rename df rows from list

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, row, python-3.5

I have looked at many similar questions, yet I still cannot get pandas to rename the rows of a df from a list of values from another df. What am I doing wrong?

```
def calculate_liabilities(stakes_df):
    if not stakes_df.empty:
        liabilities_df = pd.DataFrame( decimal_odds_lay.values * stakes_df.values ) #makes df with stakes rows, decimal odds columns
        stakes_list = stakes_df.to_dict()
        print(stakes_list)
        liabilities_df = liabilities_df.rename(stakes_list)
        return liabilities_df
    else:
        print ("Failure to calculate liabilities")
```

`stakes_list = stakes_df.to_dict()` gives the following dict:

```
{'Stakes': {0: 3.7400000000000002, 1: 5.5999999999999996, 2: 7.0700000000000003}}
```

I want the rows of liabilities_df to be renamed 3.7400000000000002, 5.5999999999999996 and 7.0700000000000003 respectively.

Comment: not clear your requirement, please check the doc to know how to use rename https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to rename liabilities_df's row name(index) to stakes_df's value, you need to give dict not dict of dict.

```
liabilities_df = liabilities_df.rename(stakes_list['Stakes'])

example:
df= pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3

df.rename({0: 3.7400000000000002, 1: 5.5999999999999996, 2: 7.0700000000000003})

      0
3.74  1
5.60  2
7.07  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the rows with a data.frame, here you have a dictionary, that's why.

would be better if you gave us the data, but here you don't have to make a dictionary from stakes_list